# Google Chrome Extension to highlight and alert all links on a webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am a newbie in writing Google Chrome Extensions. I (specifically) intended to make a `browser action` extension which when clicked would open all the links(URLs) on a page resulting when we `Google Search` any topic.
Till now I'm able to make something which *`highlights`* and ***`alerts`***`(javascript alert function )` the links present on any webpage.
The `manifest.json` and the `script` file required are given below:-

**`manifest.json==>`**

`{`
  `"name": "Highlight then alert.",`
  `"description": "Highlight and alert links on a webpage.",`
  `"version": "1.1",`
  `"background": {`
    `"scripts": ["write.js"]`
  `},`
  `"permissions": [`
    `"tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"`
  `],`
  `"browser_action": {`
      `"default_title": "highlighter",`
      `"default_icon": "highlight_16x16.png"`
  `},`
  `"manifest_version": 2`
`}`

**`write.js==>`**

`chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {`

**`var action_url1 = "javascript:(function()`
`{for(i=0;i<document.links.length;i++)alert(document.links[i]);})();";`**

 
**`var action_url2 = "javascript:(function()`
`{for(i=0;i<document.links.length;i++)document.links[i].style.backgroundColor='#F00';})();";`**
`chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: action_url1});`
`chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: action_url2});`
`});`
Right now, I am writing a simple `inline` javascript code , storing them in different variables as shown and then passing them into the Chrome Object method
- **`chrome.tabs.update()`** to perform the the `highlight` and `alert` operation.
I need to figure out a way to perform the same operation by writing an absolute javascript function rather than passing through a variables.
Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little bit unsure exactly what you want, but my guess is you want a way of injecting the code your testing on a Browser Action click without that bookmarklet style your doing right now.
If so, this is how I do it...
**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Testing from a PopUp",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Inject Test Script",
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version":2
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"injectedCode.js"});
window.close();
```

**injectedCode.js**

```
log = function() {
    for(i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) console.debug(document.links[i]);
}

highlight = function() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('div[id="search"] ol li h3 a');
    for(var i = 0,length=links.length>10 ? 10 : links.length; i < length; i++) links[i].style.backgroundColor = '#F00';
}

log();
highlight();
```

The bit you should look up is executeScript
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript
Personally I like this way for testing little bits before turning them into content scripts.

Comment: The above is really a neat way of testing an extension. This is helpful.

Comment: Your answer is acceptable as you have given a solution to one part of my question of not writing the inline js.

Comment: @learn_to_code Im not sure what your other part/s where?  Anyways, I changed the highlight bit to only target the links that open a page and limited it to ten.  Prob with that is I cant guarentee that it will always work, it worked for me but I cant guarente its going to work for other people as the results may be rendered different under other circumstances.  You may benefit from starting another question asking specifically how to target the links that open a page on a google search results page and dont limit the question to just chrome extensions, but FF/opera aswell as its all relevant.

Comment: Great.As you said it may render different results under other circumstances,it is working nearly on most of the links.

Answer (score 3):

Sample Skeleton which will highlight all links in extension for Google Search, you customize it as you need. Let me know if you need more information

[image]

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name": "Show Links",
  "description": "Show links in a page",
  "version": "0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "16.0.884",
  "permissions": [
    "experimental", "tabs", "downloads","<all_urls>"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.jpg",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

***popup.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='popup.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id='links'>
  <tr>
    <th><input type='checkbox' checked id='toggle_all'></th>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

***popup.js***

```
var allLinks = [];
var visibleLinks = [];

// Display all visible links.
function showLinks() {
  var linksTable = document.getElementById('links');
  while (linksTable.children.length > 1) {
    linksTable.removeChild(linksTable.children[linksTable.children.length - 1])
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < visibleLinks.length; ++i) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var col0 = document.createElement('td');
    var col1 = document.createElement('td');
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.checked = true;
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.id = 'check' + i;
    col0.appendChild(checkbox);
    col1.innerText = visibleLinks[i];
    col1.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
    col1.onclick = function() {
      checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
    }
    row.appendChild(col0);
    row.appendChild(col1);
    linksTable.appendChild(row);
  }
 }



// Add links to allLinks and visibleLinks, sort and show them.  send_links.js is
// injected into all frames of the active tab, so this listener may be called
// multiple times.
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(links) {
  for (var index in links) {
    allLinks.push(links[index]);
  }
  allLinks.sort();
  visibleLinks = allLinks;
  //console.log(links);
  showLinks();
});

// Set up event handlers and inject send_links.js into all frames in the active
// tab.
window.onload = function() {


  chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (currentWindow) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, windowId: currentWindow.id},
                      function(activeTabs) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        activeTabs[0].id, {file: 'send_links.js', allFrames: true});
    });
  });
};
```

***send_links.js***

```
// Send back to the popup a sorted deduped list of valid link URLs on this page.
// The popup injects this script into all frames in the active tab.
console.log("Injected");

var links = [].slice.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
console.log(links);
links = links.map(function(element) {
  // Return an anchor's href attribute, stripping any URL fragment (hash '#').
  // If the html specifies a relative path, chrome converts it to an absolute
  // URL.
  var href = element.href;
  var hashIndex = href.indexOf('#');
  if (hashIndex >= 0) {
    href = href.substr(0, hashIndex);
  }
  return href;
});

links.sort();

// Remove duplicates and invalid URLs.
var kBadPrefix = 'javascript';
for (var i = 0; i < links.length;) {

  if ((((i > 0) && (links[i] == links[i - 1])) ||
      (links[i] == '') ||
      (kBadPrefix == links[i].toLowerCase().substr(0, kBadPrefix.length))) ) {
    links.splice(i, 1);
  } else {
    ++i;
  }
}
console.log(links);

chrome.extension.sendMessage(links);
```

Comment: I have studied your code many times. I added a submit button in the pop-up which would open all the 'checked'(check-box) links into new tabs but it did not work. I made a separate function in which i have used `chrome.tabs.create()` function to open all the links which are `'checked'`.

Comment: @learn_to_code: My code will not create new tabs, it essentially builds links right at popup.html

Comment: Okay. I'm trying to find out a way to loop through the links that you have generated in the popup.js so that i can use them to create new tabs for those which are checked. Hope i am making myself clear.

Comment: You have used `checkbox.checked = true;` to check all the check-boxes. My idea is giving the value to be `false` so that a user can check the links as per the requirements. After which there would be a submit button at the end which will open all the checked links in new tabs.But i am unable to use my code into yours to accomplish the same.

Comment: @learn_to_code: May be you can set `checkbox.checked = true;` to `checkbox.checked = false;` and try opening new tab with chrome.tabs.create() API by passing URL of checkbox code